# Slice ng-repeat with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An easy question from a noob in Angular.

I have my ng-repeat like this:

```
ng-repeat="f in drillDownList['D' + 
 d.merchMetrics.DEPT_NBR + 'CG' +
 d.merchMetrics.CATG_GRP_NBR + 'C' + 
 d.merchMetrics.DEPT_CATG_NBR]
```

and I want to slice the last record because it's alway empty and it comes like that from the WS but I dont know how to achive this in AngularJS.

Comment: Do it in service or controller where you receive the data. Not in view

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time,

Do you have an example?

Comment: simple way is use `pop()` on the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `ng-repeat` you have available a variable `$last`.

example

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4]">
  <div ng-if="!$last">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

See more https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `limitTo` filter.

```
ng-repeat="f in drillDownList['D' + 
 d.merchMetrics.DEPT_NBR + 'CG' +
 d.merchMetrics.CATG_GRP_NBR + 'C' + 
 d.merchMetrics.DEPT_CATG_NBR] | limitTo:-1"
```

Alternatively, just show the last item in the list.

```
<div data-ng-bind="drillDownList['D' + 
 d.merchMetrics.DEPT_NBR + 'CG' +
 d.merchMetrics.CATG_GRP_NBR + 'C' + 
 d.merchMetrics.DEPT_CATG_NBR][drillDownList['D' + 
 d.merchMetrics.DEPT_NBR + 'CG' +
 d.merchMetrics.CATG_GRP_NBR + 'C' + 
 d.merchMetrics.DEPT_CATG_NBR].length-1]"
</div>
```

Might I suggest that you do all that concatenation in the Controller? If you do it on the View side, it's going to execute every digest.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

I'll consider your suggestion, I'm learning so any good advices is welcome =)